How to make Sumatra use synctex with Kile?
This question is not directly related to Tex but to the its software environment. I believe this place might be the better location to ask.
I am working on Windows (10). My standard Editor is Kile and my standard PDF viewer is SumatraPDF.
I would like to arrange that whenever I double click in my PDF, it opens the tex file in Kile. When an instance of Kile is already running, then I want the tex file to be opened in the instance of Kile.
I am already compiling my document with synctex, as in: -synctex=1.
Currently, when I double click in Sumatra, it opens the file using Notepad++.
So I guess the issue is more about how to configure Sumatra to do the desired thing.

This is just a starting point. The method below only addresses the issue of "whenever I double-click on my PDF, it opens the .tex file in Kile." However, it always opens a new instance of Kile. For the issue of "When an instance of Kile is already running, I want the .tex file to open in the existing instance of Kile" additional configuration is required.
To set up inverse search in SumatraPDF, follow these steps:

Open SumatraPDF and go to Settings > Options.
In the Inverse search command-line field, enter the following command:

"D:\kile\bin\kile.exe" "%f" --line "%l"

Make sure to replace "D:\kile\bin\kile.exe" with the correct path to your own installation of Kile.

This will configure SumatraPDF to open Kile and jump to the corresponding line when you click on the document.

welcome to TeX SE!

Thank you. This works as expected. Do you have any hint how to avoid opening a new instance?
